# Why is this not rendering on react

Tags: reactjs

I do get information from the user, store it in the `localStorage`, then I loop through it to create a note for each element in the storage, also im trying to use `useState()` to keep track of `localStorage` and render the notes dinamically, not sure if thats correct

```
// react and styled-components imports

    function Challenge19() {
        const [storage, setStorage] = useState(localStorage);
        const [isTitleAvailable, setIsTitleAvailable] = useState(false);
        const [errorTitle, setErrorTitle] = useState();


    useEffect(() => {
        if (isTitleAvailable) {
            setErrorTitle('Available title.')
        }
        else {
            setErrorTitle('Try another title.')
        }

    }, [isTitleAvailable]);
    
    
    function createNote(){
        const noteTxt = document.getElementById('createNote').value;
        if (isTitleAvailable) {
            const title = document.getElementById('title').value;
            localStorage.setItem(title , noteTxt);
        }
        setStorage(localStorage)
    }

    function handleClear(){
        localStorage.clear();
        setStorage();
    }

    function deleteNote(key) {
        localStorage.removeItem(key);
        setStorage(localStorage);
    }

    function verifyTitle(event) {
        if (event.target.value in localStorage) {
            setIsTitleAvailable(false);
        } 
        else {
            setIsTitleAvailable(true);
        }
    }

    return (
        <div id='box'>
            {Object.entries(storage).forEach(([key, value]) => {
                return (
                    <Create key={key}>
                        <textarea value={value} readOnly />
                        <button onClick={() => deleteNote(key)} >Delete Note!</button>
                        <button onClick={() => handleClear()} >Edit Note!</button>
                    </Create>
                )
            })}

        <Create>
            <input autoComplete="off" placeholder='Name' type='text' id='title' onChange={(event) => verifyTitle(event)}/>
            <p>{errorTitle}</p>
            <textarea name='createNote' id='createNote' />
            <button onClick={() => createNote()} >Create Note!</button>
            <button onClick={() => handleClear()} >Remove all Notes!</button>
        </Create>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Challenge19;
```

The problem is this part:

```
{Object.entries(storage).forEach(([key, value]) => {
                return (
                    <Create key={key}>
                        <textarea value={value} readOnly />
                        <button onClick={() => deleteNote(key)} >Delete Note!</button>
                        <button onClick={() => handleClear()} >Edit Note!</button>
                    </Create>
                )
            })}
```

If I use `object.keys()` or `object.values()` with `.map()` I can loop and render, but in this case I need both, keys and values, and is not rendering anything that way.
What is wrong with my code? Is this intended not to render? Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing stopping you from `.map`ping the entries - all of `Object.keys`, `Object.values`, and `Object.entries` give you an array that you can iterate over.

```
{Object.entries(storage).map(([key, value]) => (
                    <Create key={key}>
                        <textarea value={value} readOnly />
                        <button onClick={() => deleteNote(key)} >Delete Note!</button>
                        <button onClick={() => handleClear()} >Edit Note!</button>
                    </Create>
               ))}
```

Comment: Im just straight up dumb, thx for your answer man